# Image preprocessing for binary classification

Tags: python

I have a dataset with extracted frames of faces. The images are named like real_001.jpg and fake_001.jpg I want to seperate the folder into 2 sub folders of real and fake labelled images. So, that I can use it to split into train test and validation.

I have tried using the os.mkdir and joining the path but am not getting the expected output.

Comment: You added a bunch of unrelated tags to the question. The only one you really need is `python` and it's not on the list.

Comment: You don't need a program for this.   Just `mv real* realdir` and `mv fake* fakedir`, or `move` if you're using Windows.

Comment: There are lots of questions on Stack Overflow that discuss how to move files. Your question doesn't seem to indicate any special circumstances that might cause the usual approaches to fail. Since you've tried something that didn't work, _show us what you tried!!_ See [ask] and the [question checklist](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260648/843953),
and how to provide a [mre].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this small python script :

```
import os
os.mkdir("/where/you/want/reals") #create the dir for real images
os.mkdir("/where/you/want/fakes") #create the dir for fakes images

d = "/the/path/to/your/images/to/sort"

for f in os.listdir(d) : # give a list of file names id the dir d
    filepath = d + os.sep + f # (d is the dir file path, os.sep is "/" or "\" depending on your OS and f is the filename)
    if "fake_" in f : 
        os.rename(filepath, "where/you/want/fakes/" + f #move the file in the good dir
    elif "real_" in f : 
        os.rename(filepath, "where/you/want/reals/" + f
```

And that should do it.

Comment: cool ! :), with pleasure